# Django-rest-framework: have different orderingfilter for different fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple model below:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I am using django rest framework for api endpoints.

```
class IngredientListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IngredientListSerializer
    filter_backends = [OrderingFilter]
```

I wanted my two end points to output as:

```
?ordering=name  -- i want the ordering to be case-insensitive
?ordering=-name  -- i want the ordering to be case-insensitive
```

the only way to achieve this is create

```
class CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)

        if ordering:
            new_ordering = []
            for field in ordering:
                if field.startswith('-'):
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field[1:]).desc())
                else:
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field).asc())
            return queryset.order_by(*new_ordering)

        return queryset
```

and then

```
class IngredientListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all().order_by(Lower('name'))
    serializer_class = IngredientListSerializer
    filter_backends = [CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter]
```

But now when i access the following endpoints

```
?ordering=id  -- it shows 1,10,11,12
?ordering=-id  -- it shows 99,98 ..100..
```

If i use `filter_backends = [OrderingFilter]` instead of `filter_backends = [CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter]`

```
?ordering=id  -- it shows 1,2,3,4,
?ordering=-id  -- it shows 220,221,220
```

so how to tell Django to use

```
filter_backends = [CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter] for name field and
filter_backends = [OrderingFilter] for id field
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest having a specific class attribute for case insensitive fields

```
class IngredientListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all().order_by(Lower('name'))
    serializer_class = IngredientListSerializer
    filter_backends = [CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = () # include both normal and case insensitive fields
    ordering_case_insensitive_fields = () # put here only case insensitive fields
```

Then your custom ordering class will be:

```
class CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
        insensitive_ordering = getattr(view, 'ordering_case_insensitive_fields', ())

        if ordering:
            new_ordering = []
            for field in ordering:
                if field in insensitive_ordering:
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field[1:]).desc() if field.startswith('-') else Lower(field).asc())
                else:
                    new_ordering.append(field)
            return queryset.order_by(*new_ordering)

        return queryset
```

Comment: Using filter_backends looks more flexible way. I have a query. Why can't we mention ordering_fields = ('name') as a property inside CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter rather than mentioning in IngredientListAPIView

Comment: Can you look at https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5606#event-1348371639.  and answer there.

Comment: i get errro: 'Query' object has no attribute 'aggregates' if i use ordering_fields = ('__all'__). If i use ordering_fields = ('id','name') it works perfectly

Comment: Using `ordering_case_insensitive_fields` inside of `IngredientListAPIView` gives you possibility to reuse `CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter` in other views as well. If you put `ordering_fields = ('name', ) ` as property inside `CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter` that will couple the filter backend to your `IngredientListAPIView`.

Answer (score 0):

**views.py**

```
class IngredientListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IngredientListSerializer

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        if "name" in self.request.query_params.get("ordering"):
            return CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
        else:
            queryset = OrderingFilter().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
            return SearchFilter().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
```

Comment: But what if i want to add SearchFilter along with Ordering filter. Which we can do by `filter_backends = [SearchFilter,CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter]`. How to incorporate it in the filter_queryset method

Comment: I added to post. Can you see my edited answer? Is this what you want ?

Comment: its returning html instead of JSON

Comment: It's not possible. There is problem in renderer classes.

Comment: @origamic `filter_backends` should be defined as class view attribute, in order to specify available filtering options in a flexible way.

Comment: Sorry it worked. `self.request.query_params("ordering"):` should be `self.request.query_params.get("ordering"):`

Answer (score 0):

Here is fixed ordering class from answer by @Gabriel Muj

```
class MyOrderingFilter(filters.OrderingFilter):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
        insensitive_ordering = getattr(view, 'ordering_case_insensitive_fields', ())

        if ordering:
            new_ordering = []
            for field in ordering:
                if field in insensitive_ordering or (field.startswith('-') and field[1:] in insensitive_ordering):
                    # Use case insensitive ordering for listed fields
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field[1:]).desc() if field.startswith('-') else Lower(field).asc())
                else:
                    new_ordering.append(field)
            return queryset.order_by(*new_ordering)

        return queryset
```